# In Python: Different values when casting

Tags: python

Why does variable 'a = 123465789123456789' have a different value than variable 'b = int(123456789123456789.0)'?

Comment: What do you get for `b`?

Comment: Not related but your numbers aren't the same anyway, decimal or not.  Look closely at the number order for variable a.

Comment: I got 5 less in b then in a.

Oh yes, I was mistyping the number. Thats not wos I was up to though XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because python’s float (like in any other language) have a limit in precision, and you’ve reached it. On contrary, python’s integer type is of arbitrary precision, meaning that you’ll never reach its limit.